# Setting a DataGridView column that is data bound to type of int

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm loading a `csv` file into a `DataGridView` through `WindowsForm` control and it is automatically setting all columns to strings so they are sorted alphabetically.

The columns are

```
Product description (String)
Item Code (String)
Current Count (Integer)
On Order (String)
```

When `Current Count` column is sorted, it go in this order 1,2,22,3,35,36,4,40 and so on.

Also these columns and rows are not hard coded, I am reading the file and loading it into a `DataGridView` control.

How can I make so that table's row are sorted numerically relatively to `Current Count` column's values.

This is the code used to input the csv file into the `DataGridView`

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Size = new Size(800, 650);
    dataGridView.Size = new Size(440, 550);
    dataGridView.Location = new Point(15, 15);

    dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
  
    string[] dataFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
    //File.Copy("C:\\StockFile\\stocklist.csv", "C:\\StockFile\\stocklistNew.csv", true);

    string[] dataCollection = null;
    int x = 0;
    foreach (string text_line in dataFile)
    {
        dataCollection = text_line.Split(',');  
        if(x ==0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i <= dataCollection.Count() -1; i++)
            {
                dataTable.Columns.Add(dataCollection[i]) ;
            }                   
            x++;
        }
        else
        {
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataCollection);
        }
    }
    
    dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
    this.Controls.Add(dataGridView);

    dataGridView.Columns["Item Code"].ReadOnly = true;
    dataGridView.Columns["Product Description"].ReadOnly = true;
    dataGridView.Columns["On Order"].ReadOnly = true;
}
```

Comment: What framework do you use? Where does that `DataGridView` class come from? Many frameworks allow registering a custom comparator for sorting columns. You would have to register a comparator that converts strings to numbers and then compares the numbers.

Comment: Also, could it be that your code is C# and not C++? In case you are using the Windows Forms DataGridView there is a tutorial for doing custom sorting on columns here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-customize-sorting-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Yes sorry it is c# and Windows forms, i wasnt sure how to post and i made that mistake. I've had a play around with those custom sorting and it doesn't seem like they work on my program. I've updated my code here to show you how my form is loading and was wondering if there is a way to say when it gets to the "Current Count" column, for it to set the typeof to int?? Also im not sure if i made it clear, but i want to be able to click on the header and it order them from least to most in int values if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the column type when creating it.

```
if (dataCollection[i] == "Count") // or "Current Count"
    dataTable.Columns.Add(dataCollection[i], typeof(int));
else
    dataTable.Columns.Add(dataCollection[i]); // typeof(string) by default
```

Without explicitly specifying it, the type will be `string`.

Comment: Thank you so much Alexander, Ive been plagued with this for a while now.:)